Какой знак требуется на месте пропуска?
Он ужасно злился (?) нет, он был в бешенстве настолько, что едва различал наши слова.
Какой знак следует поставить на месте пропуска? Объясните, пожалуйста.

Здесь, думаю, применимы правила Розенталя о Тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении.
Он ужасно злился – нет, он был в бешенстве настолько, что едва различал наши слова.
Вторую часть БСП можно рассматривать как присоединение или, скорее, как противопоставление. (Он не просто ужасно злился, а был в бешенстве.)
Ещё подходит вариант с многоточием:
Он ужасно злился... нет, он был в бешенстве настолько, что едва различал наши слова.

Слово "нет", выражающее утверждение и отрицание, в составе предложения отделяется или выделяются запятой
